# Recursive definition of the relation greater than on N X N

Tags: relations

Give a recursive definition of the relation greater than on N X N using the successor operators s?

I started this question throw this way:

basis: (1,0) ∈ N x N

could someone help me in recursive step?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(n,m) \in \ >$ then

$(S(n),m) \in \ >$ and

If $n \neq S(m)$

$(n,S(m)) \in \ >$

Answer (score 1):

My favorite recursive definition of $>$ for natural numbers is:

$(0,n) \notin \,>$ and

$(m+1,n)\in\,>\iff [(m,n)\in\,>\text{ or }m=n]$.

Answer (score 0):

How about: if $(a,b) \in >$ then $(a+1,b)\in >$ and $(a+1,b+1)\in >$.  (Here I am using $(x,y)\in >$ to signify $x>y$.)

Comment: Nice! Simpler than mine!

Comment: @Jonas Gomes: Yours looks good too. They're pretty similar.

Comment: what about the Closure ? [a,b] ∈ N x N it can be obtained from (1,0)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

$$\forall x \forall y (x < y \leftrightarrow (s(x)=y \lor \exists z (x < z \land s(z) = y)))$$